# Couldn't read my external disk

Tags: partitioning, mount

My External disk couldn't be read by fdisk or GParted, but when I ran `lsblk` ->

```
......

sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  99.5G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   605M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   604M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   1.6T  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0   100G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I tried `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb` ->

```
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

anything I could do?

Comment: Your lsblk output suggests that sdb is a blank device with no partitions. Are you expecting to see existing partitions and data? What happens if you connect the device to a different computer?

Comment: Yes, there was a partition. and It couldn't be read on other computers. I tried to create a new partition using `parted` by `mklabel gpt` command it give me Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb

Comment: Did you format drive without having partition(s) or copy an ISO to drive? Either of those writes data into the area on drive where partition table normally is, and then drive cannot be read. If no data, just zero out partition table area and then you can create new partitions. Better to use gpt partitions.Post in question: `sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb`